# Am I running the right linear model with interactions in R and how do I interpret the results?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme, linear-model

Data description:
I have a continuous measure (called value in this example) in cases and controls ("group" in my data = categorical). There is another categorical variable called cluster, which includes 19 clusters.

**The question I want to answer is: does a specific "cluster" significantly contribute to the "value" in cases or controls?**

here is a much reduced sample of the data:

```
    structure(list(group = c("case", "control", "case", "case", "control", 
"case", "control", "control", "case", "control", "control", "control", 
"case", "control", "control", "control", "control", "case", "case", 
"case", "case", "case", "case", "case", "control", "case", "control", 
"control", "control", "case", "case", "case", "case", "control", 
"control", "case", "case", "case", "case", "control", "control", 
"case", "case", "control", "case", "case", "case", "case", "case", 
"case", "case", "control", "control", "case", "control", "control", 
"control", "case", "case", "case", "control", "case", "control", 
"case", "case", "control", "case", "control", "case", "control", 
"control", "case", "control", "case", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "case", "case", "control", "case", 
"control", "case", "case", "case", "control", "case", "control", 
"case", "case", "control", "control", "control", "case", "case", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"case", "control", "control", "case", "control", "case", "case", 
"case", "control", "control", "case", "control", "case", "control", 
"case", "case", "case", "case", "case", "case", "case", "case", 
"control", "control", "case", "control", "control", "case", "case", 
"control", "control", "case", "control", "case", "control", "case", 
"case", "control", "control", "case", "control", "control", "case", 
"case", "case", "case", "control", "case", "control", "case", 
"control", "case", "control", "control", "control", "case", "control", 
"case", "control", "case", "control", "control", "control", "case", 
"case", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"case", "control", "case", "control", "control", "control", "case", 
"control", "case", "control", "case", "case", "case", "control", 
"control", "control"), emm = c("M197", "M197", "M197", "M197", 
"M197", "M197", "M197", "M197", "M197", "M197", "M238.1", "M1", 
"M238.1", "M238.1", "M1", "M238.1", "M238.1", "M238.1", "M1", 
"M238.1", "M39.4", "M12", "M39.4", "M39.4", "M39.4", "M12", "M39.4", 
"M12", "M39.4", "M12", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3", 
"M3", "M3", "M3", "M54.1", "M54.1", "M36.2", "M36.2", "M54.1", 
"M54.1", "M54.1", "M54.1", "M36.2", "M36.2", "M71", "M71", "M71", 
"M71", "M71", "M71", "M100", "M100", "M71", "M100", "M123", "M123", 
"M123", "M123", "M123", "M123", "M123", "M123", "M123", "M123", 
"M52", "M53", "M116.1", "M86", "M108.1", "M108.1", "M225", "M86", 
"M116.1", "M52", "M4", "M4", "M4", "M4", "M4", "M4", "M4", "M4", 
"M4", "M4", "M90.5", "M76", "M104", "M104", "M90.5", "M104", 
"M90.5", "M68", "M92", "M104", "M58", "M82", "M103", "M103", 
"M25", "M25", "M25", "M82", "M87", "M58", "M88", "M89", "M8", 
"M114", "M77", "M88", "M2", "M88", "M77", "M28", "M42", "M75", 
"M81", "M81", "M75", "M75", "M75", "M65", "M59.1", "M11", "M19.4", 
"M19.4", "M19.4", "M19.4", "M19.4", "M19.4", "M19.4", "M19.4", 
"M19.4", "M19.4", "M218", "M218", "M218", "M218", "M218", "M218", 
"M218", "M218", "M218", "M218", "M233", "M233", "M233", "M233", 
"M233", "M233", "M233", "M233", "M233", "M233", "M6", "M6", "M6", 
"M6", "M6", "M6", "M6", "M6", "M6", "M6", "M74", "M74", "M74", 
"M74", "M74", "M74", "M74", "M74", "M74", "M74", "M95", "M95", 
"M95", "M95", "M95", "M95", "M95", "M95", "M95", "M95"), cluster = c("A-C2", 
"A-C2", "A-C2", "A-C2", "A-C2", "A-C2", "A-C2", "A-C2", "A-C2", 
"A-C2", "A-C3", "A-C3", "A-C3", "A-C3", "A-C3", "A-C3", "A-C3", 
"A-C3", "A-C3", "A-C3", "A-C4", "A-C4", "A-C4", "A-C4", "A-C4", 
"A-C4", "A-C4", "A-C4", "A-C4", "A-C4", "A-C5", "A-C5", "A-C5", 
"A-C5", "A-C5", "A-C5", "A-C5", "A-C5", "A-C5", "A-C5", "D1", 
"D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
"D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", 
"D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", 
"E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E2", "E2", "E2", "E2", "E2", "E2", 
"E2", "E2", "E2", "E2", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E3", 
"E3", "E3", "E3", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E4", 
"E4", "E4", "E6", "E6", "E6", "E6", "E6", "E6", "E6", "E6", "E6", 
"E6", "M19", "M19", "M19", "M19", "M19", "M19", "M19", "M19", 
"M19", "M19", "M218", "M218", "M218", "M218", "M218", "M218", 
"M218", "M218", "M218", "M218", "M233", "M233", "M233", "M233", 
"M233", "M233", "M233", "M233", "M233", "M233", "M6", "M6", "M6", 
"M6", "M6", "M6", "M6", "M6", "M6", "M6", "M74", "M74", "M74", 
"M74", "M74", "M74", "M74", "M74", "M74", "M74", "M95", "M95", 
"M95", "M95", "M95", "M95", "M95", "M95", "M95", "M95"), value = c(1.67493633682419, 
0.527719293818939, 0.2689287915906, 0.689474766178069, 0.4596018735363, 
1.04266236885904, 1.04862822606469, 1.21955054842648, 2.2221488724578, 
0.304010349288486, 0.26505129371331, 1.08988355167394, 1.35590972063281, 
0.860076472547506, 3.39632740508824, 2.51096422961796, 1.58928631010814, 
0.858006042296072, 2.67486842321354, 3.26392951004592, 0.671126700225339, 
2.93177675958816, 1.82700343785732, 0.612478534630795, 0.515222482435597, 
2.48732435301179, 0.339287328276203, 25.0873221216041, 0.807626371279997, 
2.72033783948183, 3.59698015283028, 4.59588728540179, 1.91318229369593, 
1.11467699072122, 2.04682397855237, 1.25299554946936, 3.8297520661157, 
2.9033491915005, 3.04670912951168, 1.38026932084309, 1.42047833777679, 
0.904883906353742, 2.89979790070124, 1.01200446677834, 2.60446455037077, 
0.78622816032888, 0.509063444108761, 0.560243788091889, 3.43239720018805, 
11.7518405720458, 7.10946610283949, 0.792982456140351, 3.66633842097944, 
3.7886761467312, 0.490149695353586, 1.02926744742183, 0.783755000547137, 
1.21369502251105, 0.644306131857999, 9.99086332937607, 1.31548074473348, 
1.47772684947675, 0.756560580681184, 2.35567438545893, 0.798504883190201, 
0.601580796252927, 2.59074550588531, 0.769251753478011, 3.15167488439071, 
0.40274207369323, 0.740154231998592, 1.24614594039054, 1.69796954314721, 
1.52215380735561, 4.07291852971965, 1.70308483290488, 1.27877786127484, 
0.651346604215457, 0.580901136889058, 0.598804054374022, 4.38281988240757, 
1.06936732960155, 1.00391598433606, 2.39589416265026, 1.61432926829268, 
4.54666250995012, 0.990269032627361, 50.2243230272227, 2.56640959725793, 
20.4166821000289, 1.46028168953449, 7.77473467990414, 4.27193109574351, 
2.44642682728354, 0.569740564604422, 2.33806404657933, 43.2898462949919, 
2.52907068328135, 1.07010026819102, 2.06801438821701, 0.028, 
9.39998267298135, 1.36169547904001, 1.27343814619957, 1.30904502603418, 
1.73170958917302, 0.419880034275921, 2.31108483801768, 0.40274207369323, 
69.0825540760082, 4.45402941829345, 1.31046376238484, 1.08467481659845, 
1.02256186317322, 0.917494008901061, 0.771915131211614, 1.03392831007445, 
2.35119098726816, 3.0513188477151, 15.4503835734395, 3.74224785530064, 
1.9057962112165, 42.2470646632538, 2.59798758233586, 0.902202002493353, 
1.76057022494736, 0.758733624454148, 3.27957728334461, 2.61742125094694, 
1.96234818735663, 0.484210526315789, 0.657391102261111, 1.88137326551293, 
1.19466704177661, 0.028, 1.17516105837426, 0.248928995105975, 
3.19706035437705, 0.625636752105822, 0.846217012347608, 0.336858006042296, 
0.028, 0.909492062502629, 0.821597267392049, 1.12488256302766, 
2.27448941368677, 2.13544283189626, 0.546651402404121, 3.5312686464223, 
1.04310742277547, 2.38632364304786, 1.43209277735638, 0.890738071362088, 
0.708840518335651, 1.37426141404584, 3.11900826446281, 0.663157894736842, 
3.33025418859973, 2.39641802582983, 1.57515515534647, 0.379573170731707, 
1.7858029450421, 0.380533747095339, 0.57086652153991, 0.40274207369323, 
1.04900821873103, 1.5687693304891, 1.37162403671406, 2.21544641293667, 
1.59536072214714, 0.690234011053627, 0.320130215032928, 0.817251764242788, 
0.028, 1.23769338959212, 0.028, 2.35292907810806, 0.534289535343949, 
0.150456646769551, 0.028, 2.29786983127808, 2.41911982955871, 
5.52542758328376, 0.999537594008842, 1.82112362201535, 3.87273587847803, 
0.75226586102719, 0.40274207369323, 1.94323144104803, 3.04686972790841
), log.value = c(0.223998304452625, -0.277597027395885, -0.570362699600587, 
-0.161481623774078, -0.337618209607734, 0.0181436995294186, 0.0206215434970611, 
0.0861998058368955, 0.346773151058999, -0.517111631646589, -0.576670071644381, 
0.0373800983378174, 0.13223077423883, -0.065462932327511, 0.53100954946632, 
0.399840525938654, 0.201202142455468, -0.0665096537286811, 0.427302423935671, 
0.51374077087574, -0.17319548279023, 0.467130897834671, 0.261739364561656, 
-0.212909127297721, -0.288005194202818, 0.395732421996218, -0.469432360108753, 
1.3994543061979, -0.0927895085565353, 0.434622842531124, 0.555938041504896, 
0.662369369030979, 0.281756352868055, 0.0471490364688093, 0.311080496091745, 
0.097949528420861, 0.583170659137507, 0.46289927242199, 0.483830993941115, 
0.13996383505638, 0.152434615140448, -0.0434071357827536, 0.462367731116635, 
0.00518242939399978, 0.415718450583024, -0.104451405114734, -0.293228088568361, 
-0.251622950165272, 0.5355975390451, 1.07010589109139, 0.851836987889151, 
-0.100736420861109, 0.564232549982579, 0.578487483686541, -0.309671262956252, 
0.0125282375882041, -0.105819675248181, 0.0841095708576916, -0.190907735455732, 
0.999603018054213, 0.119084495510129, 0.169594164283314, -0.121156290638607, 
0.372115259641641, -0.097722423625594, -0.220706035804879, 0.413424753465148, 
-0.113931505122809, 0.498541410848774, -0.394972998109653, -0.130677773341143, 
0.0955689070059493, 0.229929895942249, 0.182458538315557, 0.609905723013308, 
0.231236281283138, 0.106795108981102, -0.186187846700017, -0.235897773559645, 
-0.222715267804095, 0.641753623133123, 0.0291269117724513, 0.00169736911778306, 
0.379467629413356, 0.207992120731825, 0.657692718553902, -0.00424680185413556, 
1.70091409161196, 0.40932597067996, 1.30998516660857, 0.164436639627109, 
0.890685577246185, 0.63062423910952, 0.388532230526275, -0.244322858379557, 
0.368856403615819, 1.63638604380911, 0.402960967315967, 0.0294244729019244, 
0.315553556037725, -1.55284196865778, 0.973127053064005, 0.134079995565443, 
0.104977855136623, 0.116954584840965, 0.238475061818367, -0.376874776016857, 
0.36381588836386, -0.394972998109653, 1.83936838565008, 0.648753081166884, 
0.117425016115208, 0.0352995570561343, 0.00968959151756701, -0.0373967629447609, 
-0.112430445872296, 0.0144904269412456, 0.371287908303069, 0.484487591637186, 
1.18893926575181, 0.573132548162559, 0.280076459221557, 1.62579653944341, 
0.414637070934121, -0.0446962132936752, 0.245653352722801, -0.119910669077737, 
0.515817869522134, 0.417873624145082, 0.29277606850338, -0.314965773607274, 
-0.182176178357607, 0.274474968368247, 0.0772468826332749, -1.55284196865778, 
0.0700973916884439, -0.60392451407393, 0.504750834997212, -0.203677747211735, 
-0.0725182478602879, -0.472553126391539, -1.55284196865778, -0.0412010868438741, 
-0.0853410138588406, 0.0511071847662579, 0.356883919803865, 0.329487949387603, 
-0.262289533399185, 0.547930758407247, 0.0183290358630477, 0.377729344136479, 
0.155971154416476, -0.0502499849481063, -0.149451465519076, 0.138069352722752, 
0.494016525512463, -0.178383055835266, 0.52247738320396, 0.379562577688894, 
0.197323338945953, -0.420704492279924, 0.251833534842369, -0.41960682239568, 
-0.243465425441042, -0.394972998109653, 0.0207788908013305, 0.195559090266087, 
0.137235087204653, 0.345461249810031, 0.202858895497118, -0.161003644799684, 
-0.494673333657209, -0.0876441332130805, -1.55284196865778, 0.0926130714204023, 
-1.55284196865778, 0.371608836886811, -0.272223331875272, -0.822588621539221, 
-1.55284196865778, 0.361325423325807, 0.383657381395024, 0.74236589138438, 
-0.000200866814948078, 0.260339427693231, 0.588017879007523, 
-0.123628646679982, -0.394972998109653, 0.288524528641044, 0.483853885906298
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-190L), groups = structure(list(cluster = c("A-C2", "A-C3", "A-C4", 
"A-C5", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E6", 
"M19", "M218", "M233", "M6", "M74", "M95"), .rows = list(1:10, 
    11:20, 21:30, 31:40, 41:50, 51:60, 61:70, 71:80, 81:90, 91:100, 
    101:110, 111:120, 121:130, 131:140, 141:150, 151:160, 161:170, 
    171:180, 181:190)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Sample of data (note I have logged the values (log.value) for normality and in doing so had to replace a bunch of 0 values with the lowest value in my original data ~0.02):

```
> head(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   cluster [1]
  group   emm   cluster value log.value
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1 case    M197  A-C2    1.67     0.224 
2 control M197  A-C2    0.528   -0.278 
3 case    M197  A-C2    0.269   -0.570 
4 case    M197  A-C2    0.689   -0.161 
5 control M197  A-C2    0.460   -0.338 
6 case    M197  A-C2    1.04     0.0181
```

I carry out the linear model:

```
lm_cluster <- lm(log.value ~ group + cluster + group:cluster , data = data)
```

and check the interaction plot (using "interactions" package):

```
colourCount = length(unique(data$cluster))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))
getPalette(colourCount)    

cat_plot(lm_cluster, pred=group, modx = cluster , plot.points = F, geom = "line", colors = getPalette(colourCount))
```

[image: interaction group:cluster]

And indeed there seems so be an interaction between "clusters" and "group" (cases/control).

The model output:

```
   Call:
lm(formula = log.value ~ group + cluster + group:cluster, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.42798 -0.26535  0.00047  0.23107  1.26215 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)              -0.02859    0.20176  -0.142  0.88752   
groupcontrol             -0.17652    0.28534  -0.619  0.53709   
clusterA-C3               0.28028    0.30264   0.926  0.35586   
clusterA-C4               0.22411    0.27319   0.820  0.41331   
clusterA-C5               0.47543    0.26417   1.800  0.07389 . 
clusterD1                 0.25247    0.25720   0.982  0.32785   
clusterD2                 0.49321    0.28534   1.729  0.08592 . 
clusterD3                 0.29978    0.28534   1.051  0.29510   
clusterD4                 0.16760    0.37746   0.444  0.65766   
clusterE1                 0.70211    0.26417   2.658  0.00871 **
clusterE2                 0.91875    0.30264   3.036  0.00282 **
clusterE3                 0.80197    0.32948   2.434  0.01609 * 
clusterE4                 0.43137    0.27319   1.579  0.11641   
clusterE6                 0.53037    0.26417   2.008  0.04645 * 
clusterM19                0.14751    0.28534   0.517  0.60592   
clusterM218               0.04118    0.27319   0.151  0.88038   
clusterM233               0.20305    0.30264   0.671  0.50329   
clusterM6                 0.15135    0.30264   0.500  0.61773   
clusterM74                0.26070    0.37746   0.691  0.49084   
clusterM95                0.39427    0.28534   1.382  0.16907   
groupcontrol:clusterA-C3  0.01271    0.40771   0.031  0.97518   
groupcontrol:clusterA-C4  0.11830    0.40771   0.290  0.77209   
groupcontrol:clusterA-C5 -0.10427    0.42230  -0.247  0.80532   
groupcontrol:clusterD1    0.03144    0.45676   0.069  0.94522   
groupcontrol:clusterD2   -0.27600    0.40353  -0.684  0.49503   
groupcontrol:clusterD3   -0.24101    0.40353  -0.597  0.55122   
groupcontrol:clusterD4    0.08780    0.45676   0.192  0.84782   
groupcontrol:clusterE1   -0.29067    0.42230  -0.688  0.49231   
groupcontrol:clusterE2   -0.54324    0.40771  -1.332  0.18472   
groupcontrol:clusterE3   -0.72173    0.42230  -1.709  0.08949 . 
groupcontrol:clusterE4   -0.15031    0.40771  -0.369  0.71289   
groupcontrol:clusterE6   -0.09571    0.42230  -0.227  0.82102   
groupcontrol:clusterM19  -0.46204    0.40353  -1.145  0.25400   
groupcontrol:clusterM218 -0.13259    0.40771  -0.325  0.74547   
groupcontrol:clusterM233  0.20025    0.40771   0.491  0.62402   
groupcontrol:clusterM6   -0.08227    0.40771  -0.202  0.84036   
groupcontrol:clusterM74  -0.86768    0.45676  -1.900  0.05937 . 
groupcontrol:clusterM95  -0.03700    0.40353  -0.092  0.92707   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4512 on 152 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4051,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2603 
F-statistic: 2.798 on 37 and 152 DF,  p-value: 5.719e-06
```

As suggested a formal test of the interaction with aov shows overall no significant interaction:

```
annova <- aov(lm_cluster)
summary(annova)
 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
group           1   2.97  2.9750  10.305 0.00162 **
cluster        18   8.04  0.4468   1.548 0.08100 . 
group:cluster  18   5.06  0.2810   0.974 0.49304   
Residuals     152  43.88  0.2887                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am struggling to interpret these results.

So there seems to be no significant interaction at a cutoff of 0.05 (a couple at p<0.1) between "group" and "cluster" . As the interactions are all "non-significant" (groupcontrol:clusterE1   -0.29067    0.42230  -0.688  0.49231),is it right to say when controlling for "group" the effect is not significant? This may be completely wrong framing or interpretation.

So all in all, and going back to my original question, (as there are no really significant interactions) no specific cluster is significantly increased or decreased when controlling for which group the participants are in?

A final question. My original data includes an "ID" column, and as the ID is repeated across patterns (so each participant identified by ID, is measured across all patterns), should I be including a random effect for repeated measures, something like this:

```
lmer_cluster <- lmer(log.value ~ group + pattern + log.value:pattern + (1|ID), data = data)
```

Session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] RColorBrewer_1.1-2        interactions_1.1.3        jtools_2.0.3             
 [4] mosaic_1.6.0              mosaicData_0.17.0         ggformula_0.9.4          
 [7] ggstance_0.3.3            arm_1.10-1                MASS_7.3-51.5            
[10] caret_6.0-86              lattice_0.20-38           broom_0.5.5              
[13] lmerTest_3.1-2            lme4_1.1-21               Matrix_1.2-18            
[16] statisticalModeling_0.4.0 readxl_1.3.1              ggfortify_0.4.9          
[19] forcats_0.5.0             stringr_1.4.0             dplyr_0.8.5              
[22] purrr_0.3.3               readr_1.3.1               tidyr_1.0.2              
[25] tibble_3.0.0              ggplot2_3.3.0             tidyverse_1.3.0          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] minqa_1.2.4          colorspace_1.4-1     ellipsis_0.3.0       class_7.3-15        
  [5] leaflet_2.0.3        rprojroot_1.3-2      ggdendro_0.1-20      fs_1.3.2            
  [9] rstudioapi_0.11      farver_2.0.3         remotes_2.1.1        ggrepel_0.8.2       
 [13] prodlim_2019.11.13   fansi_0.4.1          lubridate_1.7.4      xml2_1.2.5          
 [17] codetools_0.2-16     splines_3.6.3        polyclip_1.10-0      pkgload_1.0.2       
 [21] jsonlite_1.6.1       nloptr_1.2.2.1       pROC_1.16.2          dbplyr_1.4.2        
 [25] ggforce_0.3.1        compiler_3.6.3       httr_1.4.1           backports_1.1.5     
 [29] assertthat_0.2.1     lazyeval_0.2.2       cli_2.0.2            tweenr_1.0.1        
 [33] htmltools_0.4.0      prettyunits_1.1.1    tools_3.6.3          coda_0.19-3         
 [37] gtable_0.3.0         glue_1.3.2           reshape2_1.4.3       Rcpp_1.0.4          
 [41] cellranger_1.1.0     vctrs_0.2.4          nlme_3.1-144         crosstalk_1.1.0.1   
 [45] iterators_1.0.12     timeDate_3043.102    gower_0.2.1          ps_1.3.2            
 [49] testthat_2.3.2       rvest_0.3.5          mosaicCore_0.6.0     lifecycle_0.2.0     
 [53] devtools_2.2.2       scales_1.1.0         ipred_0.9-9          hms_0.5.3           
 [57] curl_4.3             memoise_1.1.0        gridExtra_2.3        pander_0.6.3        
 [61] rpart_4.1-15         stringi_1.4.6        desc_1.2.0           foreach_1.5.0       
 [65] boot_1.3-24          pkgbuild_1.0.6       lava_1.6.7           rlang_0.4.5         
 [69] pkgconfig_2.0.3      htmlwidgets_1.5.1    recipes_0.1.10       labeling_0.3        
 [73] processx_3.4.2       tidyselect_1.0.0     plyr_1.8.6           magrittr_1.5        
 [77] R6_2.4.1             generics_0.0.2       DBI_1.1.0            mgcv_1.8-31         
 [81] pillar_1.4.3         haven_2.2.0          withr_2.1.2          survival_3.1-8      
 [85] abind_1.4-5          nnet_7.3-12          modelr_0.1.6         crayon_1.3.4        
 [89] utf8_1.1.4           usethis_1.5.1        grid_3.6.3           data.table_1.12.8   
 [93] callr_3.4.3          ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2 reprex_0.3.0         digest_0.6.25       
 [97] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1  stats4_3.6.3         munsell_0.5.0        sessioninfo_1.1.1
```

Comment: What makes you think there is an interaction? Not a single one of the product terms was significant. You could formally test whether an interaction is present using the `aov` function.

Comment: I have edited the post to reflect this, sorry. In my actual data there are a few significant interactions  in specific clusters, which may change things but still I get the feeling my question is still not being answered by this model... Thanks